# How to get selection object from react-native webview

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have an app where I'm using react-native webview to display a document.

The user can select some text and perform some custom action that I provide.

How do I get the selection object from webview *into* my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 0.37.0 onwards there is a new feature in RN that might help you. There is a new prop in the `WebView`: [onMessage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onmessage) and also a new method, `postMessage` that enable two-way communication. From the WebView, you have to call `window.postMessage`, and it will invoke the function that you define as callback for `onMessage`. You can see a full example [in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#examples). As for getting the selected text, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379408/2628463).