# About injectScript in WebView for React-Native

Tags: reactjs, webview, react-native

WebView loads a web page

I need to call the React-Native component method in the page

```
class Mwap extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.injectScript = `
        function setTitle(title){
            mwap.MyClick();
        }
    `;
}

componentDidMount(){
    window.mwap = this;
}

MyClick(){
    console.log('Call me');
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MwapHeader
                goBack={this.goBack.bind(this)}
                closeWebView={this.closeWebView.bind(this)}
                toonShare={this.toonShare.bind(this)}
            />
            <View style={styles.line}/>
            <WebView
                ref={(ref) => {
                    this.webView = ref;
                }}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                style={styles.webView}
                source={{uri: this.props.url}}
                injectedJavaScript={this.injectScript}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                decelerationRate="normal"
                startInLoadingState={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

I injected a function with injectScript

This function calls a method of the Mwap component

I set the window.mwap = this;

But in the page, window.mwap is undefined

How do I call the React component method in a WebView loaded web page?

please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript code that you inject does not have any connection to your React Native JavaScript code. The `mwap` variable that you use in the injected JS does not have anything to do with that of your component. I'm afraid this behavior is not allowed. However, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774475/2628463) for an alternative, or the [react-native-webview-bridge](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge) package.